# How to make a button animation that shows rings onClick

Tags: android, animation, button

I want to be able to show all buttons pop out by showing rings onClick before going to another activity instead of shaking which is what it does now. Please help, thanks!

main_activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:background="@color/black"
            >




            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="910dp"
                android:orientation = "vertical"
                android:background="@mipmap/home"
                android:id = "@+id/content_fram">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150sp"
                    android:layout_height="150sp"
                    android:orientation = "vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="150sp"
                        android:layout_height="150sp"
                        android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:textSize="32sp"
                        android:textColor = "@color/black"
                        android:background="@mipmap/timebackground"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Animation.InputMethod"
                        android:orientation = "vertical"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150sp"
                    android:layout_height="150sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="150sp"
                        android:layout_height="150sp"
                        android:id="@+id/temperature"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Animation"
                        android:background="@mipmap/temperature"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation = "vertical"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150sp"
                    android:layout_height="150sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="200sp"
                        android:layout_height="180sp"
                        android:id="@+id/Weight"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Animation"
                        android:background="@mipmap/weight"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor = "@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:background="@drawable/length"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Weight"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="@mipmap/money"
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Length"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="@mipmap/metric"
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Metric"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout6"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout6"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout6"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Money"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="202sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Temperature"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textColor = "@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout3"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout3" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout7"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:background="@mipmap/food"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout8"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout7"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:background="@mipmap/data"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Food"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout7"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout7"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout7"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:text="Data"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/text"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout8"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout8" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </ScrollView>
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:name="course.labs.converjz.adView"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/adview"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/blue"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.class:

```
 final Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        final Button Metric = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout6);
        Metric.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                r.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Metric.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });
        final Button Time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time);
        final RelativeLayout r2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
        Time.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r2.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Time.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }
        });
        final Button Temperature = (Button) findViewById(R.id.temperature);
        final RelativeLayout r3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout3);
        Temperature.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r3.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Temperature.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }
        });
        final Button Weight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
        final RelativeLayout r4 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        Weight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r4.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Weight.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }
        });
        final Button Length = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final RelativeLayout r5 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout4);
        Length.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r5.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Length.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });
        final Button Money = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final RelativeLayout r6 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout5);
        Money.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r6.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Money.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
        final Button Food = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final RelativeLayout r7 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout7);
        Food.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r7.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Food.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
        final Button Data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        final RelativeLayout r8 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout8);
        Data.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                r8.startAnimation(shake);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the Animation.AnimationListener :

```
shake.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Metric.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Hopefully I understood your problem correctly and this will help.

Due to your animation, you can use just the pulsing one :

```
ObjectAnimator pulsingAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(mYourCustomButton,
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.2f),
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.2f));

pulsingAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
pulsingAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);

pulsingAnimation.start();
```

Comment: I meant something like this but much easier to program.   http://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Ejg.gif

Comment: So you just need that kind of animation, to be exact a ready solution? Sorry I've miss-clicked from mobile app, so the other answer was made accidentally.

Comment: yeah but for each button that I have on my main_activity

Comment: I changed it so it would pop out the relativelayout instead, looks better. It didn't show any rings but it did pop out which is something that I like so I'm good with that. One more question how can I make it wait til its done popping out and comes back to its original state and waits like a couple nanoseconds before going on to another activitiy?